# Getting regex expression from a string

Tags: c#, .net

I have various fields in a database which show the format that a string needs to be in in order for a user's code to match. E.g. 'A1234567' (the letter 'A' followed by any 7 digits).

In the code I want to be able to match a string that the user inputs to that format. E.g. the user inputs 'A4561234' and this is a match but 'B1234567' is not a match.

Is there a way of doing this without having to store a regex expression in the database? The format will not always be A followed by 7 digits, it might be 10 digits or a letter followed by 3 digits for example, depending on the type of code and account, which is why I need to use what's in the database and not put regex in the code as it will be different for each user.

Comment: So are you trying to take an example, and generate regex from it? Or will the user enter an expression to use?

Comment: The user will enter their code e.g. 'A4561234' and I want to check that it matches the format which is in the database, whatever that format may be. So yes, I guess trying to generate regex from what's in the database? @John

Comment: In that case I imagine you can simply store the expression as text in the database, pull it out when you need it, and then construct the `Regex` object in C#.

Comment: @John What I am missing: _Who_ is going to construct that regex string?

Comment: Thanks John. Yes @Fildor that is my concern - I am guessing each different format will need a developer to construct the regex string for every different code format?

Comment: That seems likely, yes.

Comment: Well, if you want a user with no programming skills to input the mask, you could use, for instance `#` to sinalize any number and some other character, like `%` to sinalize any letter. Any other character would be a literal match. It's doable for simple masks, and the user don't need to know regex. So, your first example the mask would be `A#######`.